# ffmpeg - where to save the video I plan to cut to frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg up and running on my computer.

Now I am trying to cut a video into individual frames. The video is titled IMG_2299.MOV.

I am using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i img_2299.mov $filename%12d.jpeg`

Two questions:
1) where do I need the actual video saved for this to work? In the same folder as the ff* executable files (/usr/loca/bin)?
2) And where will the images created be saved?

I can run the command above -- but I don't see any results.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` will try to get the file where you are executing the code. If you run this command on `~/Desktop` then it will try to grab the `~/Desktop/img_2299.mov` file and save the frames in `~/Desktop/$filename%12d.jpeg`. If your file is `IMG_2299.MOV`, then pass in the same way. Linux is case-sensitive.

Comment: @valdeirpsr This following code won't execute and the video is saved in this same folder too (in the Lion_Mountain_Lion_Mavericks_Yosemite_El-Captain_15.05.2017 folder on my desktop): `Kyles-MacBook-Pro:Lion_Mountain_Lion_Mavericks_Yosemite_El-Captain_15.05.2017 kmeloney$ ffmpeg -i IMG_2299.MOV $filename%12d.jpeg`

Comment: What exactly is the error output?

Comment: @TheSHEEEP `IMG_2299.MOV: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well, that seems relatively clear. It doesn't find the input file. So the file simply does not exist where you execute the command or has a different name (mind the case!).

Answer (score 0):

Normally ffmpeg is in your `/usr/local/bin` which means you can launch it from any path on your machine and use relative path. That means you can just go to the source directory of your video and run  `ffmpeg -i myfile.mov` and it will find it. However if you change folders, you have to keep track and probably modify, to be sure, you can always use **absolute path's** as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/you/Desktop/img_2299.mov /Users/you/Desktop/filename.%8d.jpeg
```

Just make sure, that your target directory exists and you probably don't need `12 digits` as this would be able to hold `11 million hours` of film material.  To be on the save side you can have `6`, which will be enough for `12 hours` of material